# What are the idMso's for the sensitivity & analysis groups on the home tab?

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I need to hide the sensitivity & analysis groups on the EXCEL home tab of a custom application, but I can't seem to find the group idMso for them anywhere, anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aanalysis: GroupIdea

Sensitivity: GroupClassifyLabelProtect

I found the idMso by modifying the ribbon under file > options > Customize Ribbon.
I created a new tab and moved the sensitivity & analysis groups into it and then  clicked OK to save my changes. I then went back to file > options > Customize Ribbon to export my customizations. After opening the file "Excel Customizations.exportedUI" I found this

```
<mso:tabs>
<mso:tab idQ="mso:TabHome">
<mso:group idQ="mso:**GroupIdeas**" visible="false"/>
<mso:group idQ="mso:**GroupClassifyLabelProtect**" visible="false"/>
</mso:tab>
<mso:tab id="mso_c1.F0B62B6" label="my ribbon" insertBeforeQ="mso:TabInsert">
<mso:group id="mso_c2.F0B62C5" label="my group" imageMso="ViewDisplayInHighContrast" autoScale="true"/>
<mso:group idQ="mso:**GroupClassifyLabelProtect**"/>
<mso:group idQ="mso:**GroupIdeas**"/>
</mso:tab>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find built-in ribbon control IDs in the [Office 2016 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745). For newer Office version check out the [Office Fluent UI Command Identifiers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers) for more information.

Also you can use the `Customize Ribbon` dialog (see Excel options) to find the control IDs, you just need to hover over the element in the dialog window to get a popup with a control ID.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, however, a. theses groups aren't listed in the 2016 excel control workbook (I believe they are brand new and I couldn't find a 2022 list) and b. I'm looking for the group name not the control name.

Comment: See https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers